# Group concat limit 1

Tags: mysql, magento

Here is my group concat query

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = '134',catalog_product_entity_varchar.value,NULL)) AS 'Subtitle'
```

The table contains multiple rows with 134 as the attribute id.  Really all I want to do is pull the first catalog_product_entity_varchar.value WHERE catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id=134

The full SQL is as follows

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku AS SKU,
    IF(catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id = '67',catalog_product_entity_decimal.value,NULL) AS 'Price',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id = '146',catalog_product_entity_int.value,NULL)) AS 'Brand',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = '63',catalog_product_entity_varchar.value,NULL)) AS 'Name',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = '134',catalog_product_entity_varchar.value,NULL)) AS 'Subtitle'
FROM catalog_product_entity
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_int ON catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar ON catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id          
WHERE catalog_product_entity.type_id='simple' AND catalog_product_entity.sku='30020262'
GROUP by catalog_product_entity.entity_id
```

---

*Edit: An attempt to make things clearer.*

I'm pulling off data for products.  To make things easier, try to ignore most of the query. We will concentrate only on the 'sku' and the 'subtitle'.

The first table catalog_product_entity.  We are pulling off the SKU for each product.  There is also a unique 'entity_id'.

We use the 'entity_id' when we want to pull off all associated details for this product from another table called catalog_product_entity_varchar.

The attribute id refers to which particular information you want. 134 is subtitle and 63 is the name.  There are other 'attributes' as well that each have an id.

I've used an IF statement to allow me to assign 134 to 'subtitle' and 63 to 'name'.  The table looks something like this.

```
entity_id   attribute_id   store_id   value
1                134         0        green, large
1                134         1        green, large
1                134         2        green, large
1                63          0        dakine day hiker bag
1                63          1        dakine day hiker bag
1                63          2        dakine day hiker bag
```

Notice how one product seems to have the same subtitle stored 3 times.  This is because the ecommerce platform I'm using (Magento) allows you to store a different subtitle for each store you having running (one Magento install allows multiple domains to share the same product database, but have separate subtitles/descriptions,etc)

I have used Group_Concat to grab the data and then DISTINCT to make sure I only grab one subtitle. However the problem I'm facing is that most of the time my subtitles and names are exactly the same across all stores (so Distinct works) but when there are different subtitles distinct will grab more than one subtitle.

To be honest I'm not great with MYSQL and feel I might somehow omit group_concat altogether, maybe using nested SQL statements.  Bear in mind we don't always know what store ids a product will use.

I don't really care which subtitle I grab, I just want one, the first one, the min one, the max one. Whatever.

Comment: You need to give us at least enough of the schema for the 4 tables shown to make sense of it, including the PK/FK constraints.  Your use of inner joins makes it appear that each `catalog_product_entity` must have a row in each of the sub-types; are you sure you didn't need OUTER JOIN?  But anyway, if you want what you say you want, you just join two tables.  You have to define 'first', though.

Comment: Is the entity ID column correct?  Should that last 3 rows have a different entity ID from the first three rows?  Should all 6 rows have a different entity ID?

Comment: it's correct, it's one product. 2 attributes (subtitle, name).  And there are 3 stores the product appears in (in this example), each store may hold a different name and subtitle for the one product (In this example, the names and subtitles are the same across all stores for this product)

Comment: OK; I'm beginning to see through the forest...I take it that it is not guaranteed that a particular entity ID is represented in every store, so you might have entity ID 12345 in stores 2, 3 while entity ID 1 appears in stores 0, 1, 2, so you can't just pick a store number to simplify things?  Could you mandate that all entities must be in store 0, even if the operational stores do not carry all items?  Maybe it doesn't matter...

Comment: We can infer that the `catalog_product_entity` table has columns `sku` and `entity_id` and `entity_id` is unique.  You also have a table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` with columns `entity_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id` and `value`, where the combination of the first three columns is unique.  However, you are only interested in the `entity_id` and `attribute_id` and `value`; you don't care which `store_id` is used to generate the value.  Is that correct?

Comment: Must it be raw SQL? Can you not use Magento's PHP classes for this?

Comment: BTW, I do not know of a case where Magento doesn't create the attribute for store 0. Filter by that and you should be fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Everything you said is correct.  However, after digging through the databases it looks like every attribute and entity_id _does_ always have a value for store 0.  I made a mistake and lead you to believe otherwise.  Thanks to clockworkgeek for making me double check.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> The table contains multiple rows with 146 as the attribute id. Really all I want to do is pull the first catalog_product_entity_int.value WHERE catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id=146.

What you say you want is implemented by:

```
SELECT Value
  FROM Catalog_Product_Entity_Int
 WHERE Attribute_ID = 146;
```

This might return multiple values, so you have to define what you mean by 'first'; it could be MIN, MAX, LIMIT 1, or some other criterion.

```
SELECT MIN(Value) AS Value
  FROM Catalog_Product_Entity_Int
 WHERE Attribute_ID = 146;

SELECT MAX(Value) AS Value
  FROM Catalog_Product_Entity_Int
 WHERE Attribute_ID = 146;

SELECT Value
  FROM Catalog_Product_Entity_Int
 WHERE Attribute_ID = 146
 LIMIT 1;
```

For what you say you want, I see no reason to join the other three tables or to use GROUP_CONCAT.

That leads me to suspect that you have not told us what you really want because the query shown is dramatic overkill for the stated requirement.

Comment: I edited my original post with some more info, hopefully this will help.